# Subscribe to eth3 transactions to a particular address

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to get a stream of all transactions being sent to a specific contract. Is there a way to add a filter to the below code to do that, or is it better to get all transactions and filter them as they come in?

As a followup, instead of using 'pendingTransactions' is there a way to get transactions that have been included on X blocks and can therefore be considered 'confirmed'?

```
subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function (error, result) {
}).on("data", function (transactionHash) {
        web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash)
            .then(function (transaction) {
                console.log(transaction);
            });
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly recommend taking a look at the subscription documentaion page of web3js [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html).

You're looking for a `mixed` subscription, and that will answer both your queries i.e. 1. Transactions being sent to one specific address and 2. get only confirmed transactions.

Copying and pasting directly from the documentations page

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```

In the above code `address` is the address of the contract. `topic` is generated from the event ABI. In case someone needs it, here's the way to generate the topic.

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeEventSignature('myEvent(uint256,bytes32)')
> 0xf2eeb729e636a8cb783be044acf6b7b1e2c5863735b60d6daae84c366ee87d97
```

The reason you are getting the pending transactions is because you're subscribed to `pendingTransactions`, instead use event `logs`, from there you can get the block numbers as well, as the events are fired once the transaction is carried out into the blockchain. To further determine the 'depth', you can calculate the block distance between the current event and the current blocknumber.